# discord making me verify email when certain API requests are made

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

Is there any way to get around this problem? My code looks like this:

```
import requests

token = "not gonna leak my token like I did last time lmao"
guild_id = "798596724649099305"
headers = {"Authorization": token,"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36", "Content-Type": "application/json", }
base_url = "https://discord.com/api/v8"
members_url = base_url + "/guilds/" + guild_id + "/members"
response = requests.get(members_url, headers=headers)

print(response)
```

Is there any way to get around this. I am aware this is most likely a security measure by discord. When I run this code I get a 403 response code. Then if I look in the discord app I get an orange pop up asking me to verify my email where I have to complete a captcha. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Has to do with TLS mate. Discord uses Cloudflare. Cloudflare has some basic TLS fingerprinting, you can use a cloudflare solver like:

- https://github.com/RyuzakiH/CloudflareSolverRe

Or make/fork a TLS client to get around it. Golang has some good TLS clients, I don't think there are any good, open source, python TLS clients.